# express js with synchronous function, freezing web

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I am building an app with express, and I realized I made a mistake with what I think `Promises`

this is `module.js`

```
module.exports = function(arguments){
      for(let k =1; k < something.length; k++){
      let options = {
        'url'   : linkConcat + k,
        'proxy' : 'http://' + proxArray[ii],
        'tunnel': true
      }

      promisesFor209.push(
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

          console.log('start');
          request(options, function(error, response, body){ 
               //do stuff with request (resolve or reject)
          })
        })
       )

   }
    return Promise.all(promisesFor209).then(() => {
        return someData;//dostuff
    })
}
```

This is the `main.js`

```
app.post('/mypostPath', async function(req, res) {
    try{
        var linksArrayLink = await require('./module.js')(params)
        console.log('await finished');
        //do stuff with linksArrayLink
        res.send('success');
    }catch(e){
         console.log(e); res.send('error');
    }
})
```

so it makes the whole website freeze... As I get a request it immediatly logs `start` on the terminal for all the for loop instances, then it freezes the APP until it finishes ALL the requests. Sometimes the request can take up to 5 minutes. I don't know if the proxies or the requests are slow, but yet it is a bad design that it locks the WHOLE website.

What is the better  code to do this without locking the website. still I want to wait for all the responses to return, so that I can process the data later. But How to make it without having the whole website freeze, in a secure way like i am doing with `Promises` ?

**EDIT:**

Or is it possible to do `res.send()` inside the `module.js` ? this way maybe I can get rid of the promises structure, create a counter for all the requests, and when the counter is reached, `return` or `res.send()`

From what I understand, I should NEVER use `await` in an express app (especially for operations that take time) but is there any alternative ?

Comment: This is actually amazing usage... if it didn't pause the whole app. I didn't expect it to happen since i use ```async function``` with ```app.post``` callback

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can just implement the logic by using ***Pooling*** or  WS protocol and receive the notification when it will be done.

For both methods, you should run job background!

1. Example Pooling you should  save the id of the current job and the front-end just will receive the job id and can request every 5 seconds to get the result of the current job's status
2. Example WS just keeping the connection you can be notified when the job is already done

Comment: thank you for this,

any code sample to implement ?